# stopping page refreshes with bootstrap javascript collapsible panels

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple jade template written like -

```
div(ng-if="items.length!=0")
            .panel-group(ng-repeat="item in items",ng-model="item",id="{{item.ad._id}}")
                .panel.panel-default
                    .panel-heading
                        h4.panel-title
                            a(data-toggle="collapse",data-parent="#{{item.ad._id}}",ng-href="#{{item.ad.adId}}") {{item.ad.title}}
                    .panel-collapse.collapse.in(id="{{item.ad.adId}}")
                        .panel-body.
                            {{item.ad.description}}
                .panel.panel-default(ng-repeat="bid in item.bids")
                    .panel-heading
                        h4.panel-title
                            a(data-toggle="collapse",data-parent="#{{item.ad._id}}",ng-href="#{{bid.bidId}}") Bid by: {{bid.bidderId}} At {{bid.bid}}
                    .panel-collapse.collapse(id="{{bid.bidId}}")
                        .panel-body
                            a.pull-left.btn.btn-primary Accept
                            a.pull-right.btn.btn-primary Reject
```

The data set items is coming from an $http method that gets invoked from the page controller every time I reload the page.

Here, every time I click on any panel, the page issues new requests and reloads. How do I prevent that from happening?

A screenshot of what's happening is attached below to explain the problem in more detail -

[image]

Comment: What is the version of bootstrap you use, I believe it's working properly without refreshing on [v3.2](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse) try to upgrade to it, maybe your issue will be solved.

Comment: I was using v 3.1.1, but I updated it using bower but still it did not work without refreshing

Comment: can you make a jsFiddle?

Comment: I made a fiddle, but it seems that it was working without getting refreshed. I can't create the full environment on fiddle since it involves requests from my webserver but it seems that because I am using the routeProvider every href is passed to the routeProvider which processes it and then loads the respective template again. That's why I think that my template is getting reloaded every time I click a link